# Create an Array Map using existing Array of Numbers while meeting conditions/rules in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach, while-loop

**NOTE** - Please read the information first as it contains important information to understand the problem.

Rules →

• There are **9 Columns** (C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9) [ *Max columns will be **9***]

• The number of Rows can vary from 3,6,9,12,15,18 (Max). In this case Number of Rows shall be 12

> **Number of Rows = No of Tickets (Max Allowed 6) x Rows Per Ticket (Max Allowed 3)**. Thus, **Max Rows can be 18**

• Each **Row** is required to have **4 Blank Spaces** and **5 Filled with Numbers**

• All numbers available in the Column Array **have to be utilized**

• This configuration of an shall create a matrix of **9 Columns** & **12 Rows** (*3 x 4 Tickets*), which is **108 MATRIX BLOCKS** where only a **maximum of 60 numbers can be filled out of 108 available blocks** randomly with the above conditions being met 100%.

• The numbers in column must be arranged / sorted in **ASCENDING ORDER**
(For coding logic purpose, as soon as the number is assigned to the new **MATRIX MAP** use **array_shift()** or **unset()** the number so as to avoid repetition

Example - 
**Row 1** and **Column 1** shall generate a **MATRIX BLOCK - R1C1**

**Row 3** and **Column 7** shall generate a **MATRIX BLOCK - R3C7**

**Matrix Block** can also be termed as **Matrix Cell** for your ease (if needed)

**MASTER SET OF ARRAY WITH NUMBERS**

```
array( 
    "C1"=> array( 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 ), //7 Numbers
    "C2"=> array( 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19 ), //6 Numbers
    "C3"=> array( 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 30 ), //7 Numbers
    "C4"=> array( 31, 33, 34, 36, 37, 38, 39 ), //7 Numbers
    "C5"=> array( 41, 42, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50 ), //7 Numbers
    "C6"=> array( 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 57, 58 ), //7 Numbers
    "C7"=> array( 61, 62, 64, 65, 69, 70 ), //6 Numbers
    "C8"=> array( 71, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78 ), //6 Numbers
    "C9"=> array( 82, 83, 85, 87, 88, 89, 90 ) //7 Numbers
    );
```

The above array has **60 Numbers** to be filled out of **108 MATRIX BLOCK / CELL** which meets the condition that for a **FULL BLOCK** containing **4 MINI BLOCKS WITH 3 ROWS (max. allowed) EACH**

*I have been able to generate this without any issue meeting all the conditions of the **Columns***

My **Allocation Matrix** Array will look like

```
array(
    "R1"=> array(
        "C1"=> true, // Means that MATRIX BLOCK R1C1 will be NOT EMPTY
        "C2"=> false, // Means that MATRIX BLOCK R1C2 will be EMPTY
        "C3"=> true,
        "C4"=> false,
        "C5"=> true,
        "C6"=> false,
        "C7"=> true,
        "C8"=> true,
        "C9"=> false
    ),
    "R2"=> array(
        "C1"=> false,
        "C2"=> true,
        "C3"=> false,
        "C4"=> true,
        "C5"=> false,
        "C6"=> true,
        "C7"=> true,
        "C8"=> true,
        "C9"=> false
    ),
    "R3"=> array(
        "C1"=> true,
        "C2"=> true,
        "C3"=> true,
        "C4"=> true,
        "C5"=> false,
        "C6"=> false,
        "C7"=> false,
        "C8"=> false,
        "C9"=> true
    ),
    "R4"=> array(
        "C1"=> true,
        "C2"=> true,
        "C3"=> true,
        "C4"=> false,
        "C5"=> true,
        "C6"=> true,
        "C7"=> false,
        "C8"=> false,
        "C9"=> false
    ),
    "R5"=> array(
        "C1"=> false,
        "C2"=> false,
        "C3"=> false,
        "C4"=> false,
        "C5"=> true,
        "C6"=> true,
        "C7"=> true,
        "C8"=> true,
        "C9"=> true
    ),
    "R6"=> array(
        "C1"=> true,
        "C2"=> true,
        "C3"=> false,
        "C4"=> true,
        "C5"=> false,
        "C6"=> true,
        "C7"=> false,
        "C8"=> false,
        "C9"=> true
    ),
    "R7"=> array(
        "C1"=> false,
        "C2"=> false,
        "C3"=> true,
        "C4"=> false,
        "C5"=> true,
        "C6"=> false,
        "C7"=> true,
        "C8"=> true,
        "C9"=> true
    ),
    "R8"=> array(
        "C1"=> true,
        "C2"=> false,
        "C3"=> false,
        "C4"=> true,
        "C5"=> false,
        "C6"=> false,
        "C7"=> true,
        "C8"=> true,
        "C9"=> true
    ),
    "R9"=> array(
        "C1"=> true,
        "C2"=> false,
        "C3"=> true,
        "C4"=> false,
        "C5"=> true,
        "C6"=> true,
        "C7"=> false,
        "C8"=> false,
        "C9"=> true
    ),
    "R10"=> array(
        "C1"=> false,
        "C2"=> true,
        "C3"=> true,
        "C4"=> true,
        "C5"=> true,
        "C6"=> false,
        "C7"=> true,
        "C8"=> false,
        "C9"=> false
    ),
    "R11"=> array(
        "C1"=> false,
        "C2"=> true,
        "C3"=> false,
        "C4"=> true,
        "C5"=> true,
        "C6"=> true,
        "C7"=> false,
        "C8"=> true,
        "C9"=> false
    ),
    "R12"=> array(
        "C1"=> true,
        "C2"=> false,
        "C3"=> true,
        "C4"=> true,
        "C5"=> false,
        "C6"=> true,
        "C7"=> false,
        "C8"=> false,
        "C9"=> true
    )
);
```

In the above array **R stands for Row**, **C for Column**, **TRUE/FALSE** (Boolean) means that if **TRUE** a Number can be filled in the resulting MATRIX BLOCK / CELL ( **Row[Number]Column[Number]** ) else if **FALSE** the MATRIX BLOCK / CELL shall be **EMPTY**

The result for the above shall be
[image: This is the Manual Allocation done on a Spreadsheet]

**PROBLEM** :

> I am unable to understand what should possibly be the logic & loop used here for creating a **MATRIX ALLOCATION MAP** as shown above

I have tried **while, foreach & for** but unable determine the perfect combination which would meet the conditions.

(Tried all of the above with Nested Loops also)

Comment: Ermmm... do you have a question or are you just showing some code?

Comment: @NigelRen please see section **Issue with my Code**

Comment: Please have a read of [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as it the moment there is just a mass of information and code.

Comment: I've tried to make the post informational as the situation demands to have an understanding of the rules before just randomly generating of parsing my code. I'm not asking anyone to write the code from scratch, which of course nobody would be interested in. I just want to understand what's wrong with the code as its not working as per my code.